# How to present the first view controller in a view controller container

Tags: ios5, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

Im writing a custom view controller container as per the iOS documentation on view controllers and i'm struggling on finding an elegant way to present the first view controller that also forwards the relevant display messages like `viewWillAppear:` automatically.

When i try `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:` with the `fromViewController:` as `nil` i get an error. I have resorted to animating the view into the view hierarchy with a `UIView` animation block. This seems to break the automatic forwarding of the appearance methods and means its my responsibility to call `viewWillAppear:` and `ViewDidAppear:` at the appropriate times. Is there a more efficient way to transition the first view on to the screen that takes care of the appearance and rotation methods?

My code looks a little like this for animating in the first view controller.

```
self.visibleViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self addChildViewController:self.visibleViewController];

[self.visibleViewController viewWillAppear:YES];
[self.visibleViewController.view setAlpha:0];
[self.view addSubview:self.visibleViewController.view];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                      delay:0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut 
                 animations:^{
                     self.visibleViewController.view.alpha = 1;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [self.visibleViewController viewDidAppear];
                     [self.visibleViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                 }];
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I've run into the same problem...

Comment: No, sorry. I just ended up doing viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear myself for the first view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was right there hidden in the documentation all along.

The documentation for `UIViewController` is

`- (void)beginAppearanceTransition:(BOOL)isAppearing animated:(BOOL)animated`

and the companion

`- (void)endAppearanceTransition`

Their documentation says never to call `viewWillAppear` and such from your own code. You can kick the chain off properly with these methods.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the system doesn't send your child view controller the viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear/DidMoveToParentViewController messages? This bit of the Apple docs implies that it does:

> In order for iOS to route events properly to child view controllers
>   and the views those controllers manage, your container view controller
>   must associate a child view controller with itself before adding the
>   child’s root view to the view hierarchy.

The way I read that, if you add a view controller as a child, then add the child's root view to your view, the system should send the appropriate messages as you add the view controller.

Try taking out your manual calls to those methods and set breakpoints in your child view controller to see if they still get called.

Comment: They manual calls wouldn't be there if this worked like it was supposed to. The appearance methods only seem to get called if the view is inserted into the hierarchy with `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animation:completion:` in spite of what the docs say.